# Controlling two servos via pc using mouse arduino

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

I want to control two servos via PC, using a mouse x-y coordinates. x-y coordinates of the cursor is sent to the serial port:

For the arduino part, I am getting 6 character string and dividing it into 2 parts. Then these parts are converted into integer value and send to arduino pins to set servo position:

```
 #include <Servo.h> 
    String readString, servo1, servo2;
    Servo myservo1;  // create servo object to control a servo 
    Servo myservo2;

    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    myservo1.attach(6);  //the pin for the servo control 
    myservo2.attach(7);
    }

    void loop() {}

    void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(2);  
    if (Serial.available() >0) {
     char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
     readString += c; //makes the string readString
    } 
    }

    if (readString.length() >0) {
     Serial.println(readString); //see what was received

     // expect a string like 07002100 containing the two servo positions      
     servo1 = readString.substring(0, 3); //get the first three characters
     servo2 = readString.substring(3, 6); //get the next three characters 

     Serial.println(servo1);  //print ot serial monitor to see results
     Serial.println(servo2);

     int n1; //declare as number  
     int n2;

     char carray1[6]; //magic needed to convert string to a number 
     servo1.toCharArray(carray1, sizeof(carray1));
     n1 = atoi(carray1); 

     char carray2[6];
     servo2.toCharArray(carray2, sizeof(carray2));
     n2 = atoi(carray2); 

     myservo1.write(n1); //set servo position 
     myservo2.write(n2);
   readString="";
 } 
}
```

However, the code is very slow. I need to move the mouse very slowly to make servos move. Instant movement from let's say from 50 degree to 170 takes 1 second to move the servo. Could you offer a better option to control two servos in this case?

Controlling only one servo works very well, and it moves servo instantly without any lags:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo x;

int xval;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  x.attach(9);
}

void loop() {

}
void serialEvent() {
  xval = Serial.parseInt();
  if(xval!=0) {
    x.write(xval);
  }
}
```

Code in C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            init();
        }
        private void init()
        {
            port = new SerialPort();
            port.PortName = "COM1";
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            //porty = new SerialPort();

            try
            {
                port.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
            }
        }
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Navy);
            Pen erase = new Pen(Color.White);
            x = e.X; y = e.Y;
            double curWidth = this.Width / 180;
            double x2 = Math.Round(x / curWidth);

            double curHeight = this.Height / 180;
            double y2 = Math.Round(y / curHeight);

            label1.Text = x2.ToString(); label2.Text = y2.ToString();

            string valx = x2.ToString();
            string valy = y2.ToString();
            while(valx.Length < 3)
            {
                valx = '0' + valx;
            }
            while(valy.Length < 3)
            {
                valy = '0' + valy;
            }
            string valsum = valx+valy;
            label3.Text = valsum.ToString();
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.WriteLine(valsum);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code I am taking x and y coordinates and converting it to approx 180 range. After I join the values into one string to send it through serial port.

Comment: `while (Serial.available() > 0)` will loop while a character is available, so immediately using `delay(2);` will just slow the loop. `read` the character and `if (Serial.available() == 0) delay(2);`. That way you won't wait as long as additional characters are available in the buffer.

Comment: @HABO thank you very much my friend! Now I got it. I put as you said delay when serial becomes zero in the loop, to let the string to be built and the performance increased noticably. However, anyway, there is a lag exists, because when I move mouse and sending too many frequently changing values through serial to the microcontroller, it can't cope with it... :(

Comment: Please edit your question to include the updated code. That will help others help you. You may want to try adding code to determine how many updates per second are being handled. If you are sending eight characters per update (Six digits plus two for a newline.) at 960 characters per second (Start bit, eight data bits, stop bit per character.) then you can't get more than 120 updates per second. Add a 2ms delay and that falls to about 96 updates per second. Your one servo example has no delay and only half the data transmitted, so it should be much faster.

Comment: @HABO thank you dude! For all efforts and explanations! muah =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to improve the performance of your code you can **remove the delay** and use the **maximum Baud Rate** (115200). For the sake of simplicity I compacted your Arduino code below:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

// create 2 servos x and y
Servo x;   
Servo y;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    x.attach(6);   
    y.attach(7);
}

void loop() {
    //empty
}

void serialEvent() {
   //set servo position.
   if (Serial.available()>0) { 
       //Receives 2 angles separated per a comma
       x.write(Serial.parseInt()); //Returns first angle
       y.write(Serial.parseInt()); //Returns second angle
       Serial.read(); //Read the '\n'. I am not sure if it is necessary.
   } 
}
```

Increase the Baud Rate also in the C# source code:

```
port.BaudRate = 115200;
```

In addition, I suggest you send the angles separated by a comma through the serial. So, instead of:

```
while(valx.Length < 3) {
    valx = '0' + valx;
}
while(valy.Length < 3) {
    valy = '0' + valy;
}
string valsum = valx+valy;
label3.Text = valsum.ToString();
if (port.IsOpen) {
    port.WriteLine(valsum);
}
```

Replace with:

```
if (port.IsOpen) {
    port.WriteLine(valx + ',' + valy); //Note that WriteLine appends a '\n' character in the end.
}
```

Comment: Hooray!!! It works! There is no lag at all! Thank you soooo much! Hugging and lifting up)) Im so happy!